# Hibernate Duplicate class name exception

Tags: java, hibernate, reverse-engineering

I am using Hibernate 3.5,
when I do the reverse engineering with SQL 2012 and Hibernate I am getting following error

```
org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCBinderException: Duplicate class name com.pepspb.entity.CheckConstraints generated for org.hibernate.mapping.Table(pepspb.sys.check_constraints). Same name where generated for org.hibernate.mapping.Table(pepspb.sys.check_constraints)
Duplicate class name 'com.pepspb.entity.CheckConstraints generated for org.hibernate.mapping.Table(pepspb.sys.check_constraints). Same name where generated for org.hibernate.mapping.Table(pepspb.sys.check_constraints)
<No message>
```

Can any one please tell me what is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sometimes happens when you mix the original sources with the generated ones. To resolve the issue you should separate `src` and `gensrc` at the module. And don't use `gensrc` where you have generated classes via reverse engineering as the source folder. Just compare or even better diff them and merge avoiding duplicate classes.

Comment: What if I got something of this sort:
"org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCBinderException: Duplicate class name 'CheckConstraints' generated for 'org.hibernate.mapping.Table(e2rm_maintenance_development2.sys.check_constraints)'. Same name where generated for 'org.hibernate.mapping.Table(e2rm_maintenance_development2.sys.check_constraints)'
    Duplicate class name 'CheckConstraints' generated for 'org.hibernate.mapping.Table(e2rm_maintenance_development2.sys.check_constraints)'. Same name where generated for 'org.hibernate.mapping.Table(e2rm_maintenance_development2.sys.check_constraints)'"

Comment: I am using Hibernate Tools for Eclipse... But I am getting the above error which is really confusing because the "(e2rm_maintenance_development2.sys.check_constraints‌" is mentioned as the duplicate of itself.

Comment: You should upgrade to the latest version, and follow this answer after upgrade.